# How to hide pages from wordpress admin side

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

In my WordPress site there are couple of admin roles, but i need to hide some pages from selected admin roles in admin panel, so i am just searching the way to hide some pages from the WordPress admin section. But some roles may need to show that hide pages.

I just add a sample image to get an idea about that.
According to image i want to hide **about** and **contact** pages from ABC admin role in the admin panel and it should be visible to XYZ admin role in admin panel. Hope you guys can help.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5jvW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For role wise try this code 
Use page ID in array.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts' ,'exclude_this_page' );
function exclude_this_page( $query ) {

global $pagenow;
global $current_user;
$user_roles = $current_user->roles;

if( $user_roles[0] == 'administrator' ){
    return $query;
}

if($user_roles[0] == 'editor'){
    if( 'edit.php' == $pagenow &&  'page' == get_query_var('post_type')  )
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', array(20,25) );
}
return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your function.php file

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts' ,'exclude_this_page' );
function exclude_this_page( $query ) {
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
      // If XYZ admin id is 23
        if($user_id != 23 )
                return $query;
        global $pagenow;

        if( 'edit.php' == $pagenow && ( get_query_var('post_type') && 'page' == get_query_var('post_type') ) )
                $query->set( 'post__not_in', array(10,14) ); // array page ids(contact us and abous us page ids)
        return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code .. only insert the pages to exclude and the admin ID to exclude from 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts' ,'exclude_this_page' );

```
function exclude_this_page( $query ) {
        //current user ID
        $user_id = get_current_user_id();

        //Ids of users to exclude
        $excluded_users = array(1,2,3);

        //Ids of pages to be excluded
        $excluded_pages = array(10,20,30);

        global $pagenow;

        if( 'edit.php' == $pagenow && ( get_query_var('post_type') && 'page' == get_query_var('post_type') ) ){

                if(in_array($user_id,$excluded_users)){
                    $query->set( 'post__not_in', $excluded_pages );
                }
        }
        return $query;

    }
```